# Why does the bash translation file not contain all error texts?

Tags: bash, locale

I downloaded the latest version (4.4 for now) of Bash sources from [GNU's site](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash).

I opened French translation file (`fr.po`) from `po` directory and I searched for "permission denied". There were no results.

When I open terminal and run `cd /var/log/apache2` I get the error: `bash: cd: /var/log/apache2: Permission denied`. So it IS a Bash error yet it's not included in mentioned file. Also, when I `grep -rn . -e "denied"` in the bash sources directory I only get 2 results, both of which are from file "COPYING".

Moreover, when I change Bash language with this command: `export LC_ALL=fr_FR` I get `bash: cd: /var/log/apache2: Permission non accordée`. Changing Bash language changes this error so it's another proof that this is indeed a Bash message.

Does anyone know why isn't this error included in the po file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The string comes from [`strerror(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html), which maps [error numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) to messages. In this case, it's mapping `EACCES`. The strings (and their translations) are contained in your C library.

Comment: Seems legit, thanks. [Here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc)'s the source of C library with the translations being in `po` directory.